# How to add css class to Django admin form

Tags: css, django, django-admin

I was wondering if it's possible to add a css class to the Django admin form?

For example:

```
@admin.register(SomeFunction)
class SomeFunctionAdmin(SortableAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('item1', 'item2', 'item3'),
        }),
    )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(SomeFunctionAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form

    class Media:
        js = (
            'custom.js',
        )
```

Now I want to add a css class to `SomeFunctionAdmin`, let's say I want to add `.custom-form-admin` class. And in my `custom.js` file I have some functions which search for this custom css class.

How do I add the custom css class programatically to `SomeFunctionAdmin`?

I imagne the code would look something like this:

```
@admin.register(SomeFunction)
class SomeFunctionAdmin(SortableAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('item1', 'item2', 'item3'),
        }),
    )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(SomeFunctionAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.set_css += 'custom-form-admin'
        return form

    class Media:
        js = (
            'custom.js',
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `render_change_form()` and modify the content:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


@admin.register(SomeFunction)
class SomeFunctionAdmin(SortableAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('item1', 'item2', 'item3'),
        }),
    )

    def render_change_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        content = super(SomeFunctionAdmin, self).render_change_form(*args, **kwargs).render().content
        return HttpResponse(content.replace('<form', '<form class="custom-form-admin"'))

    class Media:
        js = (
            'custom.js',
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I keep getting this error `Exception Value: 
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: Fixed the above, now it seems like I need to return the following: `Exception Value: 
expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object` on the  `return HttpResponse(content.replace('<form', '<form class="custom-form-admin"'))`

Comment: ``return HttpResponse(content.replace(b'<form', b'<form class="custom-form-admin"'))`` if you are using Python 3

Comment: Thank you. Although I am not so fond of replacing the form, it works. I hoped there would be some method to add custom css class.